# Как запретить выделение текста в инпуте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как запретить выделение текста в инпуте?

без задания disabled для него

Comment: **<input type="text" onmousedown="return false" />** но тогда будет невозможно вводить текст

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте CSS-свойство `user-select`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/user-select